# How to get slug from 'name' when editing and storing data with form request Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, request, slug

so thats
my ProductController.php

```
public function update($id, UpdateRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    $this->productsService->updateById($id, $data);
    return redirect()->route('admin.products')->withSuccess('Data updated.');
}
```

and UpdateRequest.php

```
class UpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return True;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['nullable'],
            'category_id' => ['nullable'],
            'price' => ['nullable'],
            'unit' => ['nullable'],
            'short_description' => ['nullable'],
            'description' => ['nullable'],
            'featured' => ['nullable'],
            'slug' => ["nullable"],
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to change it  automatically when the product name changes
How can I get a 'slug' from 'name' in form request when updating product data?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what are you actually asking? how to automate this or how to turn a string into a slug?

Comment: I just want to automatically change this  when updating product name...

Comment: sounds like something to do with an observer for the `updating` event of the model or via your `updateById` method you are using

Comment: creating a slug is simple.  Ensuring it is unique is more complexity that you will discover at the next stage

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the [`Str::slug`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-slug) helper method for generating slugs from a string. To use it with your `Request` you would do the following:

```
$slug = Str::slug($request->name);
```

Alternatively you could use the [sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) package from Spatie which provides a `trait` that you can add to your models which will automatically generate the slug for you when a record is created or updated.